Yearly rate change based on one or two columns in r
My data looks like this
structure(list(year = c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019), College = c("College1", "College1", "College1", "College1", 
"College1", "College1", "College1", "College1", "College1", "College1", 
"College1", "College1", "College2", "College2", "College2", "College2", 
"College2", "College2", "College3", "College3", "College3", "College3", 
"College3", "College3", "College3", "College3", "College3", "College3", 
"College3", "College3"), Department = c("Department 1", "Department 2", 
"Department 3", "Department 4", "Department 1", "Department 2", 
"Department 3", "Department 4", "Department 1", "Department 2", 
"Department 3", "Department 4", "Department 1", "Department 2", 
"Department 1", "Department 2", "Department 1", "Department 2", 
"Department 1", "Department 2", "Department 3", "Department 4", 
"Department 1", "Department 2", "Department 3", "Department 4", 
"Department 1", "Department 2", "Department 3", "Department 4"
), Enrollment = c(51L, 322L, 251L, 106L, 468L, 205L, 718L, 200L, 
344L, 256L, 434L, 38L, 487L, 503L, 14L, 448L, 489L, 437L, 695L, 
833L, 941L, 299L, 864L, 888L, 531L, 335L, 47L, 753L, 319L, 986L
)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

I am having trouble calculating the enrollment change throughout the years for each College and then for each Department. So technique I want one new column that tells me at the College level what is the enrollment change, and one new column that tells me at the Department level.
I have tried many different things and this is the closest i got
growth_rate = df %>%
arrange(College, Department)%>%
group_by(College) %>%
mutate(Diff_growth = Enrollment - lag(Enrollment), 
     Rate_percent = Diff_growth/Enrollment) 

But this code doesn't stop at the beginning of each cycle, which is the year 2017, it just keeps going down the rows.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The desired output would look like this
structure(list(X = 1:30, year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L), College = 
c("College1", 
"College1", "College1", "College1", "College1", "College1", 
"College1", 
"College1", "College1", "College1", "College1", "College1", 
"College2", 
"College2", "College2", "College2", "College2", "College2", 
"College3", 
"College3", "College3", "College3", "College3", "College3", 
"College3", 
"College3", "College3", "College3", "College3", "College3"), 
Department = c("Department 1", "Department 2", "Department 3", 
"Department 4", "Department 1", "Department 2", "Department 3", 
"Department 4", "Department 1", "Department 2", "Department 3", 
"Department 4", "Department 1", "Department 2", "Department 1", 
"Department 2", "Department 1", "Department 2", "Department 1", 
"Department 2", "Department 3", "Department 4", "Department 1", 
"Department 2", "Department 3", "Department 4", "Department 1", 
"Department 2", "Department 3", "Department 4"), Enrollment = c(51L, 
322L, 251L, 106L, 468L, 205L, 718L, 200L, 344L, 256L, 434L, 
38L, 487L, 503L, 14L, 448L, 489L, 437L, 695L, 833L, 941L, 
299L, 864L, 888L, 531L, 335L, 47L, 753L, 319L, 986L), RateChange_College = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 1.179452055, 1.179452055, 1.179452055, 1.179452055, 
-0.326209931, -0.326209931, -0.326209931, -0.326209931, NA, 
NA, -0.533333333, -0.533333333, 1.004329004, 1.004329004, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.054190751, -0.054190751, -0.054190751, 
-0.054190751, -0.195951108, -0.195951108, -0.195951108, -0.195951108
), RateChange_Department = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 8.176470588, 
-0.363354037, 1.860557769, 0.886792453, -0.264957265, 0.248780488, 
-0.395543175, -0.81, NA, NA, -0.971252567, -0.109343936, 
33.92857143, -0.024553571, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.243165468, 0.066026411, 
-0.435706695, 0.120401338, -0.945601852, -0.152027027, -0.399246704, 
1.943283582)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L
))


Please clarify if you want to calculate your columns separately/independently, i.e. one column for College and one for Department or if you want the change to be calculated for the college-department combination.

I want a new column RateChange_College that tells me college 1 from 2017 to 2018 increased 2%, from 2018 to 2019 increased 4% etc, and then another column RateChange_Department that tells me Department 1 from College 1 from 2017 to 2018 decreased 1% from 2018 to 2019 increased 3%, Department 2 from College 1 from 2017 to 2018 increseadet 10% etc

You have several values for each College for each year, so how do you want to get the % change per year for each college? I.e. for College 1, you have for values for each year.

Also, the values you are mentioning in your comment don't match the results one would get from calculating them from your data. Please provide an output dataset that exactly matches the structure and values you'd expect to get.

I updated with the desired output I used the formula (new-old)/old to calculate the rate difference and for overall college i used (sum(new)-sum(old))/sum(old)

You can calculate the rates for colleges and college-department combinations separately, and join the results.
Rates per college
library(tidyverse)

college_rates <- df |>
  arrange(year, College, Department) |>
  summarize(college_yearly_enrollment = sum(Enrollment),
            .by = c(year, College)) |>
  mutate(RateChange_College = (college_yearly_enrollment - lag(college_yearly_enrollment))/
           lag(college_yearly_enrollment),
         .by = College) |>
  select(-college_yearly_enrollment)

glimpse(college_rates)
#> Rows: 9
#> Columns: 3
#> $ year               <dbl> 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019
#> $ College            <chr> "College1", "College2", "College3", "College1", "Co…
#> $ RateChange_College <dbl> NA, NA, NA, 1.17945205, -0.53333333, -0.05419075, -…

Join to rates per college-department
df |>
  arrange(year, College, Department) |>
  left_join(college_rates, by = join_by(year, College)) |> 
  mutate(RateChange_Department = (Enrollment - lag(Enrollment))/lag(Enrollment),
         .by = c(College, Department)) |> 
  # filter for reprex only
  filter(year > 2017)
#> # A tibble: 20 × 6
#>     year College  Department Enrollment RateChange_College RateChange_Department
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <chr>           <int>              <dbl>                 <dbl>
#>  1  2018 College1 Departmen…        468             1.18                  8.18  
#>  2  2018 College1 Departmen…        205             1.18                 -0.363 
#>  3  2018 College1 Departmen…        718             1.18                  1.86  
#>  4  2018 College1 Departmen…        200             1.18                  0.887 
#>  5  2018 College2 Departmen…         14            -0.533                -0.971 
#>  6  2018 College2 Departmen…        448            -0.533                -0.109 
#>  7  2018 College3 Departmen…        864            -0.0542                0.243 
#>  8  2018 College3 Departmen…        888            -0.0542                0.0660
#>  9  2018 College3 Departmen…        531            -0.0542               -0.436 
#> 10  2018 College3 Departmen…        335            -0.0542                0.120 
#> 11  2019 College1 Departmen…        344            -0.326                -0.265 
#> 12  2019 College1 Departmen…        256            -0.326                 0.249 
#> 13  2019 College1 Departmen…        434            -0.326                -0.396 
#> 14  2019 College1 Departmen…         38            -0.326                -0.81  
#> 15  2019 College2 Departmen…        489             1.00                 33.9   
#> 16  2019 College2 Departmen…        437             1.00                 -0.0246
#> 17  2019 College3 Departmen…         47            -0.196                -0.946 
#> 18  2019 College3 Departmen…        753            -0.196                -0.152 
#> 19  2019 College3 Departmen…        319            -0.196                -0.399 
#> 20  2019 College3 Departmen…        986            -0.196                 1.94


and for example if I would like to specify the years, instead of starting from 2017 i want to start from 2018 and calculate until 2020 let's say.. how can i adjust the years?

you could change the filter on the last line to filter(between(year, 2018, 2020)).

Here's a solution that should match your desired output:
library(tidyverse)
df |> 
  arrange(College, year) |> 
  mutate(Enrollment_Year = sum(Enrollment), .by = c(College, year)) |> 
  mutate(RateChange_College = Enrollment_Year / lag(Enrollment_Year) - 1, .by = c(College, Department)) |> 
  arrange(College, Department, year) |> 
  mutate(RateChange_Department = Enrollment / lag(Enrollment) - 1, .by = c(College, Department)) |> 
  arrange(College, year, Department)

# A tibble: 30 × 7
    year College  Department   Enrollment Enrollment_Year RateChange_College RateChange_Department
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>             <int>           <int>              <dbl>                 <dbl>
 1  2017 College1 Department 1         51             730         NA                    NA        
 2  2017 College1 Department 2        322             730         NA                    NA        
 3  2017 College1 Department 3        251             730         NA                    NA        
 4  2017 College1 Department 4        106             730         NA                    NA        
 5  2018 College1 Department 1        468            1591          1.179452              8.176471 
 6  2018 College1 Department 2        205            1591          1.179452             -0.3633540
 7  2018 College1 Department 3        718            1591          1.179452              1.860558 
 8  2018 College1 Department 4        200            1591          1.179452              0.8867925
 9  2019 College1 Department 1        344            1072         -0.3262099            -0.2649573
10  2019 College1 Department 2        256            1072         -0.3262099             0.2487805
# ℹ 20 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

We first calculate the Enrollment sum per year and college in order to be able to calculate the Rate Change. We then rearrange the data by College/Department/Year and do the same Rate Change calculation (however, this time directly with the original Enrollment column).
